# Excel spreadsheet blank cell query

Tags: excel

I am having no success with the following:

I require the formula in J14 to display a blank cell when no input is provided in I14. Currently it displays the contents of E14 (see capture below)

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In your last `AND()` statement you only provide one argument. Therefore you can omit it, and shorten your formula.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your current IF in another:

```
=IF(I14<>"",IF(-96>I14,"",IF(AND(-97<I14,I14<-20),G14,E14))),"")
```

The `...` is where you put the other formula.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As an excel newbie, do you mean this?  =IF(I4<>"",IF(-96>I14,"",IF(AND(-97<I14,I14<-20),G14,IF(AND(I14>-21),E14,""))))   This leaves a FALSE response...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(OR(I14="",-96>I14),"",IF(AND(-97<I14,I14<-20),G14,IF(AND(I14>-21),E14)))
```

Here I've just added another condition to return a blank cell to your (IF) 96>I14 condition. Thus, if I14 = "" OR if -96 > I14, the cell will be blank.

Comment: Excellent! Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: I think this worked for you? If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.